# DirectX: Fastest way to draw Pixels

Tags: c#, c, directx

I have to draw several thousands of pixels per frame for a falling sand animation, up to now I drawed them with Sprite.Draw (and a 1x1 Texture), but this only worked for resolutions 256x256 or lower. So is there an faster alternative to draw individual pixels?

(Shaders will not work for my problem, since the logic is applied according to the pixels state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try drawing points. I found [this](http://www.drunkenhyena.com/cgi-bin/view_net_article.pl?chapter=2;article=20) but it is only for DirectX 9.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it Works up to 1280x800 which is what I wanted.

Comment: Fixed link to web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20210506175714/http://www.drunkenhyena.com/cgi-bin/view_net_article.pl?chapter=2;article=20